# Sort array outside method

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetWords(string path, Func<string,Boolean> s)
        {
            
            Array.Sort(array, (first, last) => first.Length.CompareTo(last.Length));
        }
```

I want to get the Array.Sort outside the GetWords method. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: what exactly do you want, question is not clear

Comment: I want to sort "string[] array" outside GetWords method?

Comment: sort again or move the sort out of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean, "I want to sort the result of GetWords, but thats not an Array, its an IEnumerable so I cant use Array.Sort - how do I do that?"

```
var list = GetWords(....);
var sorted = list.OrderBy(s=>s);
```

see [How to sort an IEnumerable<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630687/how-to-sort-an-ienumerablestring)