# Sort a collection based on the order of properties extracted from that collection

Tags: c#, .net

I currently have a method which uses `.Select` to extra all of the properties from each object in a collection into an array. Then, I do something to it which results in the array being re-ordered. I then am trying to figure out how to return an ordered list of the original objects, based on the order of each of those objects properties. I suspect that there may be a solution using LINQ which I'd like to use, but can't quite figure it out.

Worst case scenario and I'd simply not create the array of `Bar` in the example below and only refer to the original collection, but I'd like to not have to reference said `Foo` collection so frequently.

```
public class X
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public IOrderedEnumerable<Foo> OrderTheFoos()
    {
        Bar[] allBars = Foos.Select(x => x.MyBar).ToArray();
        allBars = allBars.OrderBy(x => new Random().Next()).ToArray();
        return // return a list of Foos based on the order of the array of Bars
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string name) 
    { 
        MyBar = new Bar(); 
        Name = name; 
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Bar MyBar { get; set; } 
}

public class Bar { }
```

Comment: _OrderBy Random_?  Perhaps you meant to perform a Knuth / Fisher-Yates Shuffle? See [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Comment: Your question also sounds like you just want to [Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: Your question also sounds like you are trying to sort an `IEnumerable<T>` without first transforming it to a sortable collection -- spoiler: you can't.  Even `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy` [internally](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L2543-L2551) puts things into a collection to sort them.  See [How to sort an IEnumerable<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630687/how-to-sort-an-ienumerablestring)